# Swift Callback in DNS lookup

Tags: swift, dns, callback

The following does not compile. States that the function cb is not correct. I realize this may be a simple solution, but the documentation is less than detailed. Could this be the "Swift does not support C" problem?

```
var host = "asdf.com" 
let hostRef = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, host).takeRetainedValue() 
func cb(host:CFHost, type:CFHostInfoType, error:CFStreamError, ctx:CFHostClientContext) -> () {
    println("resolve callback") 
} 
CFHostSetClient(host, cb, nil) 
let runloop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent(); 
CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop(hostRef, runloop, "myDNS resolution mode" as CFString)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile the code using an Objective-C block inside the Swift code:

```
var host = "google.com"
let hostRef = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, host).takeRetainedValue()

let hostclientCallback_objectiveC: @objc_block (CFHost!, CFHostInfoType, UnsafePointer<CFStreamError>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Void = { (host, hostinfo, error, something) in
    println("callback done")
    println(host)
    println(hostinfo)
    println(error)
    println(something)
}
let hostclientCallback_objectiveC_pointer = imp_implementationWithBlock(unsafeBitCast(hostclientCallback_objectiveC, AnyObject.self))
let hostclientCallback = unsafeBitCast(hostclientCallback_objectiveC_pointer, CFHostClientCallBack.self)

var clientContext = CFHostClientContext(version: 0, info: UnsafeMutablePointer(), retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: nil)
CFHostSetClient(hostRef, hostclientCallback, &clientContext)
var cfError: CFStreamError?
CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop(hostRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, CFHostInfoType.Addresses, nil )
```

However I don't know what to do the CFHost returning in the callback.

Comment: Your answer is inspiring, but it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code for your reference. I make sure that it works in my project.

```
var clientContext = CFHostClientContext(version: 0, info: unsafeBitCast(self, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.self), retain: nil, release: nil, copyDescription: { (i: UnsafePointer<Void>) -> Unmanaged<CFString>! in  
    // Strangely, this closure has never be called. But it can not be nil.
    let desc = UnsafePointer<ESNetworkTableViewController>(i).memory.description as CFString
    return Unmanaged<CFString>.passRetained(desc)
    //Unmanaged.passRetained(CFCopyDescription(Unmanaged.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(i)).takeUnretainedValue()))
})
var cfError = CFStreamError()
let hostRef = CFHostCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, "mazutest.3g.qq.com").takeRetainedValue()
CFHostSetClient(hostRef, { (host: CFHost, hostInfo: CFHostInfoType, error: UnsafePointer<CFStreamError>, info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) in
    print("callback done"); print(host); print(hostInfo); print(error.memory); print(info)
    let vc = unsafeBitCast(info, ESNetworkTableViewController.self)// UnsafePointer<ESNetworkTableViewController>(info).memory
    var resolved: DarwinBoolean = false
    guard let arr = CFHostGetAddressing(host, &resolved)?.takeRetainedValue() where resolved else {
         return
    }
    let data = (arr as Array).first as! NSData
    var storage = sockaddr_storage()
    data.getBytes(&storage, length: sizeof(sockaddr_storage))
    if Int32(storage.ss_family) == AF_INET {
        let addr4 = withUnsafePointer(&storage) { UnsafePointer<sockaddr_in>($0).memory }
        let ipv4Address = String(CString: inet_ntoa(addr4.sin_addr), encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        print(ipv4Address) // Here is the result.
    }
}, &clientContext)
CFHostScheduleWithRunLoop(hostRef, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode /* kCFRunLoopCommonModes */);
CFHostStartInfoResolution(hostRef, CFHostInfoType.Addresses, &cfError)
```